# Why is **read** ignoring stdin

Tags: bash, stdin

Why manually inputing values as an array using *read* command works :

```
read -a words
## type values here and then enter
```

But this does not :

```
printf "uno\tdos\n" | read -a spanishWords
echo "${spanishWords[0]}" ## This is empty
```

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both work just fine. The problem is that your second example calls `read` in a separate process. In that separate process, `spanishWords` contains the correct contents. But that doesn't help you.

This would work:

```
printf "uno\tdos\n" |
   ( read -a spanishWords;
     echo "${spanishWords[0]}" )
```

Comment: I wouldn't say "necessarily"; `ksh` doesn't, nor does `bash` if you are using the `lastpipe` option.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. I took that word out.